# Remove column and its value from string

Tags: c#

I have three strings like

```
string a = "[ERROR] = any thing And [ID] > 20 And [NAME] like Varun";
string b = "[AGE] < 60 Or [ERROR] like Exception And [ID] > 20 And [NAME] like Varun And [ERROR] = any thing ";
string c = "[ID] > 20 And`enter code here` [NAME] like Varun And [ERROR] = any thing";
```

I want to remove string that start from [ERROR] to next operator like And/Or.....

I want Answer like

```
string a = "[ID] > 20 And [NAME] like Varun";
string b = "[AGE] < 60 And [ID] > 20 And [NAME] like Varun";
string c = "[ID] > 20 And [NAME] like Varun";
```

How can I remove..???

Comment: How to: Search Strings Using Regular Expressions (C# Programming Guide) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: What you have tried yet?You can use Regex and string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't comfortable with Regular Expressions (and I'm assuming that you aren't), you can use this pseudo code:

1. Split the string into words (separate by spaces)
2. Scan the list of words, if it equals `[ERROR]` then skip all words up to the next word starting with `[` and ending with `]`
3. If the word starts with `[` and ends with `]` then add it to the output and all following words that don't start with a `[` and end with a `]`.

   ```
   public static String FilterString(string value)
   {
     string[] lsWords = value.Split(' ');
     StringBuilder lsbBuilder = new StringBuilder();

     bool lbIncluding = true;

     foreach(String lsWord in lsWords)
     {
       if (lsWord.StartsWith("[") && lsWord.EndsWith("]"))
          lbIncluding = (lsWord != "[ERROR]");

       if (lbIncluding)
       {
         if (lsbBuilder.Length > 0) lsbBuilder.Append(' ');
         lsbBuilder.Append(lsWord);
       }
     }

     return lsbBuilder.ToString();
   }
   ```

   ....

   ```
   string a = "[ERROR] = any thing And [ID] > 20 And [NAME] like Varun";
   string b = "[AGE] < 60 Or [ERROR] like Exception And [ID] > 20 And [NAME] like Varun And [ERROR] = any thing ";
   string c = "[ID] > 20 And`enter code here` [NAME] like Varun And [ERROR] = any thing";

   a = FilterString(a);
   b = FilterString(b);
   c = FilterString(c);
   ```

here's the output:

```
[ID] > 20 And [NAME] like Varun
[AGE] < 60 Or [ID] > 20 And [NAME] like Varun And
[ID] > 20 And`enter code here` [NAME] like Varun And
```

This doesn't get rid of the ANDS / ORS and so forth, you will need to do that one your self, but this should give you a nice starting point.